# How can I use my own analyzer implementation with ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer

I have implemented own Lucene Analyzer. How can I use it with ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to implement AnalysisBinderProcessor, which would make your analyzer available to elasticsearch and than wrap it into an elasticsearch plugin. The simplest way to do it is by starting with one of the [many](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-analysis-stempel) [examples](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-analysis-icu) [available](https://github.com/imotov/elasticsearch-analysis-morphology) on github.

Comment: special thanks for https://github.com/imotov/elasticsearch-analysis-morphology =)

Comment: Yeah, a little bit of self promotion never hurts ;)